# Main site accessible via CMIS, but how to access other sites and sub-sites?

Tags: 2013, site, sub-site, cmis

The main site can be accessed via CMIS URL `http://server/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories`.

But the list of repositories at this address does not seem to include other sites and sub-sites.

How to access them?

- Does they have their own, different CMIS URLs?
- Are they accessible at the same CMIS URLs via any other trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is important to **activate** CMIS for **each site and sub-site**:

[image: SharePoint site, Manage site features]

[image: SharePoint site, Activate CMIS Producer]

Once this is done, CMIS can be accessed at this endpoint URL:

```
http://site/subsite/_vti_bin/cmis/rest?getRepositories
```

*(There are various rumours about alternative URLs, for instance `http://server/sub/site/_vti_bin/ListData.svc`. And according to [this blog](http://www.armedia.com/blog/2011/05/how-to-retrieve-and-display-cmis-data-in-sharepoint-using-rest-atom-service/), the CMIS URL syntax for sub-sites is `http://server/sub/site/_vti_bin/ListData.svc/ListName`)*

Answer (score 0):

From [Technet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff934619%28v=office.14%29.aspx) I get the impression that in

```
http://web/_vti_bin/cmis/rest/[repositoryid]?command
```

the `http://web` should be the URL to the Web (site or sub-site) you want to get content from

Comment: I was just looking for it, unsuccessfully! All information I can find is for 2010, not sure if that means nothing has changed or everything has changed though...